# JAVA иконка окна

Tags: java

Начал заниматься языком JAVA SE, написал простенькую программу, сделал исполняемый jar, запустил его, почти все нормально, но вот почему-то иконка окна (верхний левый угол) пропала. Эту иконку я добавлял в область уведомлений, но ее там тоже нет, а без нее как-то не то, пустое место получается. Скажите, почему пропали иконки и как исправить? Иконку добавлял с помощью

```
new TrayIcon(new ImageIcon("src/timer/images/trayIcon.gif").getImage(), "Название программы", trayMenu);
```

Comment: TrayIcon??

Comment: да! Но эта функция для иконки панели уведомлений!  А иконка окна 
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("src/test/images/trayIcon.gif");
setIconImage(imageIcon.getImage());